# How do I connect remote MAC as build host for Xamarin on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have mac-mini configured and running at my home.
And I want to pair my Visual Studio to that mac.

Is it possible to configure it as a build host in case when it's located in a different network ?

`i.e. Mac is at home and my Windows/Visual Studio setup is at work.`

Comment: `some another network`? i.e. Your mac is at home and your Windows/Visual Studio setup is at work?

Comment: @SushiHangover yep, correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OS-X machine has to reachable by a secure shell connection (SSH) over port 22.

If you can ssh from your Windows' PC to your Mac, say using `Putty`, then yes, you can make Visual Studio/Xamarin connections to that Mac and use it as a build host.

1) You can bridge two private networks via a VPN

2) Expose your Mac (port 22) to the public Internet (buyer beware)

The key issue, other then security on your Mac, is the speed/bandwidth of your connection between the two machines. Well the amount traffic is not really heavy if you are just using it as a build-host and not using the iOS removing simulator, network latency can be a real performance killer.

If using the (new) iOS Remote Simulator, bandwidth requirements climb and the high network latency can make it a non-solution in some situations.

*(It only a Mac-Mini, almost fits in a pocket, take it to work with you ;-)*

[image]

Comment: Anyway to use a different port?

Comment: @Goddard Yes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339045/can-the-xamarin-mac-agents-port-be-configured-to-something-other-than-port-22

Answer (score 0):

Your Mac needs to be accessible via SSH (port 22) from the PC running Visual Studio.  You will need to setup a VPN or configure your home network to properly forward port 22 to the Mac.