# Can the Xamarin Mac Agent's port be configured? (to something other than port 22)

Tags: xamarin

I'm configuring my network's firewall to permit connecting to my Mac build server when I'm away from my house. I would like to set up port forwarding to send traffic to the Mac via an alternative to port 22.

Can the Xamarin Mac Agent be configured to listen on a port other than 22?
Does Visual Studio permit connecting to the Mac Agent on a port other than 22?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Zagaeski’s solution stopped working on new VS/Xamarin versions...
I am using a different approach here; on my Windows machine, I have created a port forwarding rule, like this:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=22 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=REMOTE_PORT connectaddress=REMOTE_HOST_OR_IP_ADDRESS
```

[image: CMD]

In my case, REMOTE_PORT is 17352 and REMOTE_HOST_OR_IP_ADDRESS is the hostname (DNS name or IP Address) of the remote network I am connecting to.

This way I am able to connect my Visual Studio / Xamarim to the host “127.0.0.1”, on port 22 (internally redirected to my remote host/port):

[image: VS]

Hope it helps.

Comment: screenshot links are dead

Comment: @MikeAsdf, are you sure? It seems ok to me, by instance: https://uc27d7ad4f35270fe4688a4c4184.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/cd/0/get/BCPO0f82WPD916Ha2K1ZB7WZmVBcDkAaqmm1fzDy2MiAmufDojddMRl6k1UAQSd4_iuSca9k0b1fF1t0US8_7vTqsgL4VirTfxTvJL-K1js3qQ/file?dl=1#

Comment: oh, my privacy badger extension was blocking them; apologies, disregard

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to change the port, but doing so is currently a little tricky because the login dialog does not (yet) support alternate port numbers.  To change the port you will instead need to edit a registry key by hand using `regedit.exe`.

Example steps:

1. Connect to the Mac build host successfully over port 22 as normal.  This sets up the required registry value and the SSH keys.
2. Quit Visual Studio.
3. Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to the following key:

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\MacAgent\KnownServers
4. Locate the *Name* that corresponds to your Mac build host.
5. Edit the registry value to add the new port after the IP address of the Mac build host, separated by a `:` colon.  For example, for port 20022:

   > 192.168.1.2:20022

   (The registry value includes a couple other parts separated by `|` pipe characters.  You can leave those other parts unchanged.  You only need to update the IP address.)
6. You can now change the `sshd` port on the Mac to 20022, and you will be able to connect to it from Visual Studio.  One way to adjust the `sshd` port is to edit the values for "ssh" in `/etc/services` and then turn Remote Login off and back on.

   See also:

   - https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x
   - http://marcel.zurreck.com/os-x-yosemite-change-ssh-port
   - https://www.google.com/search?q=change+remote+login+port+os+x

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: It seens that this solution stopped working on new VS/Xamarin versions... :(