# Connect to Mac running behind NAT on custom SSH port with Xamarin Mac agent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have Mac, which could be accessed from outside network via NATed port 6535 on my router; router itself exposes port 22 as well. I wish to connect from outside network via Xamarin Mac agent to my Mac.

I am able to connect both to router and Mac via SSH (Putty), but when I try to connect to Mac from Visual Studio 2017 (or MsBuild command prompt) entering in Server IP something like 1.1.1.1:6535 (where 1.1.1.1 is substituted by my router external IP) - I see by fingerprint, that Studio is using port 22 for connections (I see my routers fingerprint, instead of my Mac fingerprint).

Is it ever possible to connect to custom port from Xamarin Mac agent running in Visual Studio and **MsBuild**?

[Can the Xamarin Mac Agent's port be configured? (to something other than port 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339045/can-the-xamarin-mac-agents-port-be-configured-to-something-other-than-port-22) - suggests that I need to connect first successfully, but I could not. Importing registry keys from machine, where connection was successful does not helps, as VS is still trying to bump to remote host via port 22 which is seen by fingerprint (so, I still could not connect from Visual Studio). If I try to invoke an MsBuild directly - it also fails, because MsBuild just ignores port directive.

I start MsBuild with following cmdline at elevated developers command prompt: `msbuild mySolution.sln /t:Clean;Build /p:Configuration="Release";IpaPackageDir=C:\t\;Platform=iPhone;ServerAddress=1.1.1.1;ServerPort=6535;ServerUser=user;ServerPassword=password`

And in response I receive following:

```
_SayHello:
  Connecting to Mac server 1.1.1.1...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(63,
5): warning : Ignoring server port when the build is not running inside Visual Studio. [myprojectpath\myproject.csproj]
  Starting connection to 1.1.1.1...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(63,
5): warning : Could not authenticate the user 'user' with the provided credentials [myprojectpath\myproject.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(63,
5): warning VSX1000: A connection to the Mac Server couldn't be established with Address='1.1.1.1' and User='user', so only the main assembly was compiled for project 'myproject'. Connect to a Mac Server and try again to build
the full application. [myprojectpath\myproject.csproj]
```

Comment: You could always set up port forward on your router to forward external port 22 on router to internal port 6535 or 22 on your Mac.

Comment: No, port 22 on router is already taken and I could not exchange this assignments :(

Comment: Why not? Is it routing to a different computer already ? Or does the router not allow you to change this at all? What router do you have ?

Comment: Router is already routing port 22 to other computer and these service is in use worldwide, so I could not expose port 22 for Mac NATting. I exposed port 6535 and NATted it to port 22 on Mac - and could connect perfectly with ssh (Putty).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Xamarin Mac Agent's port be configured? (to something other than port 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339045/can-the-xamarin-mac-agents-port-be-configured-to-something-other-than-port-22)

Answer (score 0):

please see the following thread, I believe this will help you.

[Configure xamarin Mac agent port to something other than 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339045/can-the-xamarin-mac-agents-port-be-configured-to-something-other-than-port-22)

I have flagged this as I believe it is a duplicate in most senses.

Follow-up : in your router configuration, can you:

1. Temporarily assignment port mapping 22 to your Mac and test to make sure this works, you can then set it back.
2. Create a port mapping that directs "router external" (your 6*** number) to "mac IP address internal port 22" , if your router is like most, you should be able to assign this external port to the Mac's IP on port 22.

If you have trouble with this please provide screen shots of your router configuration for the above so we can assist.

Regards

Edit: added extra info

Comment: I added more data to question to clarify why it does not seems a duplicate to me. Also, post, you are referring too, implies that you shall have a successful connection first on port 22, which is not possible at my situation.

Comment: I've added more answers

Comment: It seens that this solution stopped working on new VS/Xamarin versions... :(

Comment: You may have to unblock a firewall port on your new version if they've changed security drastically perhaps.