# Is it possible to wirelessly deploy Xamarin.iOS Apps using a VPN?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, vpn

We currently have a Xamarin.Forms application that requires a Mac to build the Xamarin.iOS project. We purchased two MacMinis to do this but these are located in our office and due to Coronavirus we are all working from home for the foreseeable future. We are trying to use Microsoft's wireless deployment feature  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/wireless-deployment?tabs=windows) - this works if I'm in the office on the same network or I take the MacMini home because all hardware (laptop with VS19, MacMini and iPhone) are on the same network. However, my laptop does not detect the phone when the MacMini is in the office and my laptop plus iPhone are at home on the VPN. I'm going to speak to my companies IT department to see if it is any settings on our VPN side but any suggestions or assistance would be much appreciated!

What I've Tried:

- I've tried connecting the iPhone to the VPN and wirelessly deploy it from Visual Studio 19 but my
  device is not detected.
- I've looked for an answer through Stackoverflow's "Similar questions".
- A quick Google search didn't retrieve anything relevant to wireless debugging/deployment using a VPN.
- I've searched on Microsoft Community to see if any issue had been raised.

Comment: you can setup appcenter.ms to build your code on every checkin and create a distributable for testing.  This is awkward for a development purposes but might be an alternative to consider.

Comment: hi, we had the same issue at the beginning, do you have any co-worker present in the office? if yes you can have remote access to the mac in office via AnyDesk or Microsoft Teams n create your builds... Its not a good way but we overcome the issue like this

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, Jason :) However, we already do this for distributing but it doesn't allow a developer to debug (breakpoints and seeing where exceptions are thrown via VS)

Comment: That's an interesting approach, Blu :) I'll keep it in mind for the future. Unfortunately, our whole office is closed, only allowed access when requested.

Comment: Since you can set up debugging over network in XCode, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work, but I guess not only does your pc have to be in the VPN network, but also your phone. Maybe it helps to set up the network debugging from within the company's network to make sure it runs from "inside" and then take the phone home and connect via VPN. However, depending on the VPN implementation of your phone, it might possibly be a better way to set up a VPN bridge from your router (if the device supports it).

Comment: @MarkusMichel, I have and can confirm my PC and iPhone are connected to the same network via VPN (Check Point Endpoint Security). I have done what you're suggesting by going in the office and connecting the phone wirelessly to the company network - this works but as soon as I disconnect (use 4G) and try to connect via the VPN, VS19 no longer detects the device. With the information given, do you still thing a VPN bridge would be of any use?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986202/how-do-i-connect-remote-mac-as-build-host-for-xamarin-on-visual-studio) may help.